# Switching between files without closing vim editor

Tags: shell, vim

I'm new to command line and using vim.
Suppose you’re editing a file named `exampleFile.txt` using vim editor. How do you switch to another file named `exampleFile2.txt` without exiting vim? What command do you use? Thanks.

Comment: `:e exampleFile2.txt`

Comment: You can use `:!  vi other_file` and will return to the first when finished. Be very carefully, you can go wrong: `vi a.txt` (edit) `!vi b.txt` (edit and want something from file a.txt) `vi a.txt` (edit). After `:wq` in a.txt and `:wq` in b.txt you return to an old version of `a.txt`. Saving this file will overwrite your last edits.

Comment: See ':help hidden' and use ctrl-6 to jump back